# Rails 3: "accepts_nested_attributes_for :reject_if"    doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My UserQuestion model has many accepted_answers and accepts nested attributes for :accepted_answers

```
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :accepted_answers, :reject_if => lambda { |a| ( a[:answer_id] == 0) }, :allow_destroy => true
```

My form sends the following parameters:

```
   "accepted_answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer_id"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"answer_id"=>"25"}, "2"=>{"answer_id"=>"0"}}
```

I guess my problem is, that the lambda isn't set up right, because accepted answers are created even though their answer_id is 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
:reject_if => lambda { |a| ( a[:answer_id].to_i == 0) }
```